# Discord Bot cant leave voice channel 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'disconnect'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I started working on a music bot and I keep getting this when I try to leave. Joining a voice channel works fine.

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'disconnect'
```

And my code is

```
@client.command(name = "join",
                pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
    print("Bot joined the voice channel")

@client.command(name = "leave",
                pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
    await voice_client.disconnect()
    print("Bot left the voice channel")
```

Also im using the following libraries:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Game
import random
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `VoiceClient` in that server, then [`Client.voice_client_in`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.voice_client_in) will return `None`.  You should check for this before attempting to disconnect.

```
@client.command(name = "leave",
                pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
    if voice_client:
        await voice_client.disconnect()
        print("Bot left the voice channel")
    else:
        print("Bot was not in channel")
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, the bot is definitely with me in the channel and to my understanding the "await client.join_voice_channel(channel)" would initials the voice client. But with your code I just keep getting the Bot was not in the channel while it definitely is

Comment: @Dezert What do you get from [`Client.is_voice_connected`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.is_voice_connected)?

Comment: It still indicates that the bot is not in the voice channel. As suggested I wrote ```@client.command(name = "check",
                 pass_context = True)
async def check(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    if client.is_voice_connected(server):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")``` And I continue to get that the bot in not in the channel

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages or similar from your `join` command?

Comment: All im getting is ```CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OpusNotLoaded: ```

Comment: Then you'll have to load the opus library before using voice, with [`discord.opus.load_opus`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.opus.load_opus)

Comment: Youre a champ Patrick! That fixed it, just had to use `find_library` because it couldn't find it by itself for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The fixed version with the input from @PatrickHaugh is:

Imports:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Game
from ctypes.util import find_library
import random
from discord import opus
import nacl
import asyncio
```

Code:

```
@client.command(name = "join",
                pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    opus_path = find_library('opus')
    discord.opus.load_opus(opus_path)
    if not opus.is_loaded():
        print('Opus was not loaded')
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
        await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
        print("Bot joined the voice channel")

@client.command(name = "check",
                 pass_context = True)
async def check(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    if client.is_voice_connected(server):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")


@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
    for x in client.voice_clients:
        if(x.server == ctx.message.server):
            return await x.disconnect()

    return await client.say("I am not connected to any voice channel on this server!")
```